# Can you format these equations for me?

Tags: math-mode

Can help me formatting these (example and non-sense) equations?

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
 z + t = b \quad \forall x \in X \\
 h + g(a,b,c) + r\cdot a = f(b,c,d) \quad \forall y \in Y \\
 a = b \quad \forall z \in Z \\
 u \cdot v = h + q \forall n \in \mathbb N
\end{eqnarray*}
```

I would like to have the equality signs one below the other, the left side of the equalities aligned right towards the signs, the right term aligned left to the equality signs, and the forall-signs one below the other.

I did not manage to format this in the appropiate way. Any explanation why your solution works is appreciated as well.

Comment: Please add a document class and all necessary packages (but only necessary ones) to your code so other users don't have to guess that. (You'll have a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) then.) An image of the output would also be great.

Comment: Thank, I haven't been aware of this convention on this site. This will be added soon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Never* use `eqnarray`, *never*. Load the `amsmath` package to get its powerful alignment environments:

```
\begin{align*}
z + t                   &= b        &&\forall x \in X \\
h + g(a,b,c) + r\cdot a &= f(b,c,d) &&\forall y \in Y \\
a                       &= b        &&\forall z \in Z \\
u \cdot v               &= h + q    &&\forall n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
```

The spaces in the input are irrelevant, but are helpful to spot alignment point.

An `align` environment and its sibling `align*` (the latter doesn't number lines) builds an alignment composed of pairs of `rl` columns, so omitting entries for the third column (`&&`) will give left alignment.

Remember to say

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

in your preamble and to put the relation symbol where the alignment should be *after* the `&` separating the right aligned column from the left aligned one.

Comment: It is also possible to use `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`, because they load `amsmath` internally but providing even more power of math typing than `amsmath`

Comment: @Tobi: In the present case, what might the `mathtools` macros and environments provide for the OP's question that can't be accomplished equally well with the `align*` environment provided by the `amsmath` package? Would the syntax become easier?

Comment: The syntax would be the same since it’s the definitions of `amsmath` working here. But mathtools has some more features and I wanted to mention it here …